# Docker-compose and custom packages

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm trying to get the hang of docker and docker compose. I can set up and install the images from docker hub fine, but I'm not trying to install http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ on my container.

I don't understand where I should install this and what install instructions I should from the wkhtmltopdf install instructions. Do I add it to another dockerfile?

Currently I have nginx, php, mysql, redis, and node images (al latest I think), but I don't know where to put wkhtmltopdf. If I put it in it's own dockerfile then what image do I use as a base image (`FROM test:1`)

From what I can see, nginx means it runs on debian, but I cant get debian install instructions to work, and using apt-get wkhtmltopdf installs an older versions too :(

Answer (score 0):

You can write instructions mentioned in [this guide](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/0.12.4/INSTALL.md#others) in the dockerfile.

Comment: which dockerfile would this go in though? Isn't the point of docker to separate everything out?

Comment: And can you tel me why I use the 'other' instructions over 'linux'? Is this because of it being on docker? As I understand it, the base is still linux based, no?

Comment: You can decide the base image(ubuntu/deb etc.) of your container. For running up the container you would have to write a dockerfile, which will include the installation of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Do you have an example by any chance? I've added a Ubuntu image to my docker-compose with install instructions for wkhtmltopdf but I can't seem to call that from my code. I'm using https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle if that makes a difference?